# How much legacy Objective-C code can Hyperloop work with?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

Hyperloop looks like an exciting way forward for Appcelerator. I've read the very basic Hyperloop docs and watched the intro video. In the intro video I can see that simple Swift or Objective-C files can be used,

I'm interested to find out how much of an exisiting Swift/Objective-C codebase could be dropped into a Hyperloop project?
Could we for example, take an entire project written in Swift/Objective-C and work on it using Hyperloop?

Does anyone have any hands on experience?

Cheers!

Comment: @m02ph3u5 last post in link you gave was from 12/17/2014 - a little irrelevant ?

Comment: That's old info indeed

Answer (score 2):

You can potentially use a lot of the code but you can't (today) easily drop in a full xcodeproject without a bit of work.

If you look at the example iOS project that comes alongside Hyperloop (http://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55f74a9f421c44837717716b/Hyperloop-Module) you can see some drop in examples of both swift and objective-c code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the examples at [Loop Modules](https://loopmodules.com/) since they provide a lot of how-to for using Swift-Objective C in Hyperloop. From my own experience, you can't drop and drag a current X-Code project, every piece that is integrated into Hyperloop works as a module (they call it framework, but for me it is a module) which needs to be adapted to be used inside Titanium.

My personal experience, with enough tinkering (or knowledge) you can integrate any native Swift-Objective C component you want. I even went as far as compiling source C and integrating that in Hyperloop and calling the functions in that with C as well.

Currently I'm using Javascript, Swift, Objective-C and C in the same project and it works great so far :)

Also the latest documentation from Appcelerator is [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide)

Another good news is Hyperloop [is now available](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2017/05/free-plan-announcement/) to the free Indie program at Appcelerator.